# SQL - How to join two tables but where only certain things are exact match?

Tags: sql

I do not know if this is possible or not or where its a many-to-many join case it is complicated but here is the situation that I am looking for help on:

```
Table1:
Name  Value1 Value2 Value3
John  Demo   DAT    12.5
Jane  Dawn   RAN    13.0

Table2:
Name  Value1 Value2 Value3
LOTS OF DATA
```

Basically, I'm hoping to create a join statement where anything contained in Table 1 for value1, value2 (EXACTLY) and if value3 is not contained in Table 2 then outputs the results. Keeping in mind there is NO unique key here.

I've tried something similar to the below, but didn't seem to work:

```
Select * from Table2 as t2 inner join Table1 as t1 on t2.value1 = t1.value1
where t2.value1 = t1.value1
and t2.value2 = t1.value2
and t2.value3 <> t1.value3
```

I've also looked at unions, but wasn't 100% sure. Any help is appreciated. I figured this is something simple that I am just missing as looking to have a lookup table (Table 1) with values that Table 2 should contain properly and then output anything that isn't set properly in the Value3 column as the output so we can correct those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists` and `exists` together:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.value1 = t.value1 and
                        t2.value2 = t.value2 and
                        t2.value3 = t.value3
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.value1 = t.value1 and
                    t2.value2 = t.value2
             ) ;
```